# Why can't I use the print function inside the class when doing operator overloading?

Tags: c#

I didn't get any errors. I'm just wondering. Why it doesn't work when I typed "no4.Print();". did not class already create?

I was learning operator overloading. i noticed that it only works when i use Console.WriteLine func. If i tried to use Print function inside the class it errors.

```
using System;

class Number{
private int myNumber;

public Number(int myNumber){
    this.myNumber=myNumber;
}
public static Number operator *(Number a, Number b){
    return new Number(a.myNumber*b.myNumber);
}
public void Print(){
    Console.WriteLine(this.myNumber);
}
public static implicit operator int(Number a) {
    return a.myNumber;
}
public static implicit operator Number(int a) {
    return new Number(a);
}
}

class HelloWorld {
static void Main() {
Number no1 = new Number(5);
Number no2 = new Number(2);
Number no3 = no1*no2;
no3.Print();

int no4 = new Number(1312);
Console.WriteLine(no4);  //It doesnt work   no4.Print();

Number no5 = 2121;
no5.Print();
}
}
```

Comment: `no4` is an `int`, and that type doesn't have a `Print` method.

Comment: And the assignment of a Number to an int is only working because of autounboxing, whereas the assignment of an int to a Number is autoboxing

Comment: oops, that's right. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `no4.Print();` because the `int` type/class does not have such a method. Also, nobody is telling the variable to get converted to a `Number` object. However, when you write something like

```
((Number)no4).Print();
```

you are explicitly converting your `int` value to a `Number` object with the help of your defined `implicit operator Number(int a)` operator.